# Count number of lines with length condition

Tags: text-processing

I am trying to count the number of lines in large files with length of the line less than 300 characters.

My current approach to do this is with following command(but it is slow):

```
awk "length<=300" *.log | wc -l
```

Is there a better way to get only the count of the lines?

Comment: Is your input contains all single byte characters? or it's can contain unicode characters which are double bytes? if unicode then you want count each of characters or characters bytes?

Comment: They are UTF-8 files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `awk` to count line

```
awk 'length<=300{c++} END { print c }' *.log
```

where

- `c++` increment counter
- `END { print c }` is executed after last line and print `c` value.

I am not sure, this will be faster (at least `wc -l` won't have to count and parse lines)

---

to get subtotal (can be one lined)

```
awk 'length<=300{t++;s++} 
     ENDFILE { printf "%s:%d\n",FILENAME,s ; s=0 ; } 
     END { printf "TOTAL:%d\n",t }' *.log
```

Comment: On my data set this command was faster than using the solution with grep

Comment: You should mention that to get the subtotal that way requires GNU awk for ENDFILE. Also, `printf "TOTAL:%s\n",t` should be `printf "TOTAL:%d\n",t` so you get numeric output (`0` vs null) even if no lines are shorter than 301 chars.

Answer (score 3):

With `grep`:

```
cat *.log | grep -vc '^.\{301\}'
```

To match lines with length `<=300` we grep with `-v` (invert match) for any `301` characters, as the search pattern is limited to one line for `grep`. Pattern is anchored at the beginning of the line with `^`. And `-c` counts the matching lines.

---

If you want to have some basic progress indicator, you can use `pv` from package `moreutils`:

```
pv *.log | grep -vc '^.\{301\}'
```

---

If you want to get line number per file:

```
grep -vc '^.\{301\}' *.log
```

and if you want to get the total from the above command:

```
grep -vc '^.\{301\}' *.log | awk -F':' '{c+=$NF} END {print c}'
```

Depending on the data, although we don't usually pipe `grep` with `awk`, it could be faster than `cat` & `grep`, if there are many very long input lines, the pipe here is used just for a small amount of data, numbers and filenames.

Comment: Both solutions works well. I like yours also because I can see per file the count

Comment: @thanasisp, grep would print lines like `hello.txt:1`, `foo.txt:3` if it's given multiple filenames. `cat *.log | grep ...` would give the total, though

Comment: I used this:
grep -vc '^.\{301\}' *.log | awk -F: '{s+=$2} END {print s}'  , but in case if you need per file the count:
grep -vc '^.\{301\}' *.log > 300grep.txt and then awk

Comment: I have ~ 60GB of logs to search in

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

Dependent on shell-globbing:

```perl
raku -ne 'state $i; $i++ if .chars <= 300; END say $i // 0;'

#OR

raku -ne 'state $i; if .chars <= 300 {$i++}; END say $i // 0;'
```

Files determined via regex (independent of shell-globbing):

```perl
raku -e 'for dir(test => / .+ \.log $ /) {state $i; $i++ if .chars <= 300 for .lines; END say $i // 0};'
```

https://docs.raku.org/syntax/state
https://docs.raku.org/routine/dir
https://raku.org